# Everytime I open a new terminal I see this and don't know how to fix

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using MacOs Catalina 10.15.6 in a MacBook Pro (Mid 2012).

I'm really new at programming and I don't know why this always appear when I open my terminal:

```
Last login: Tue Jul 28 18:43:18 on ttys002
[oh-my-zsh] Insecure completion-dependent directories detected:
drwxrwxr-x  7 luigiminardi  admin  224 Jul 24 16:14 /usr/local/share/zsh
drwxrwxr-x  7 luigiminardi  admin  224 Jul 24 15:59 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions

[oh-my-zsh] For safety, we will not load completions from these directories until
[oh-my-zsh] you fix their permissions and ownership and restart zsh.
[oh-my-zsh] See the above list for directories with group or other writability.

[oh-my-zsh] To fix your permissions you can do so by disabling
[oh-my-zsh] the write permission of "group" and "others" and making sure that the
[oh-my-zsh] owner of these directories is either root or your current user.
[oh-my-zsh] The following command may help:
[oh-my-zsh]     compaudit | xargs chmod g-w,o-w

[oh-my-zsh] If the above didn't help or you want to skip the verification of
[oh-my-zsh] insecure directories you can set the variable ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX to
[oh-my-zsh] "true" before oh-my-zsh is sourced in your zshrc file.
```

All the modifications I made in `.zshrc` was to put this:

```
# ASDF INSTALLED ON BREW
. $(brew --prefix asdf)/asdf.sh
```

after that:

```
# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
```

But I don't know if is it in the right place or if is this the cause of the problem.

Comment: That's a really detailed and helpful error message. Which part of it exactly are you having trouble understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX=true` in your `zshrc` file, before  `$ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`.

This will skip the verification of insecure directories: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/lib/compfix.zsh